# Is it possible to store timer value into a variable?

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, timer, 8051

i'm using DS89C450 timer0 to count from 0 when the value of incoming data is '0' and it will only stop when the the data '1' and it will compare with the values i have. However, is it possible to store the value of how much the timer counted so i could use if loop for the comparing of the values.

For Example:

```
for(i=0;i<15;i++)
{
  if(in_data == 0)
  {  
    TH0 = 0x00;          //Set Timer0 to count from 0
    TL0 = 0x00;
    TR0 = 1;             //Start Timer0
    if(in_data == 1)             //if InputData = 1
    { 
       TR0 = 0;          //Stop Timer0
       //Store Timer0 value under "TimerValue"
     }
    if(TimerValue == 2212)         //If TimerValue = 2212(decimal)/08A4(Hex)
    {
      Data[i] = 0x00;               //Set Data[i] = 0
    }
}
```

Does anyone know is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `TH0` holds your timers value.

You should be able to find your your processors input size for this port in the handbook.

Then you can just

```
//since no more details are provided i'm assuming TH0 and TL0 are 8 bits
short TimerValue = (TH0 << 8) | TL0; // to store the value.
```

Comment: Well, TH0 and TL0 both have value of the timer. So even when storing only TH0, it is not accurate since it is missing out value of TL0

Comment: BTW this is something that is worth mentioning when making the question. The size of the port and what port contains what.

Comment: Ah sorry for not mentioning about the size of the port. And yes, both TH0 and TL0 are 8 bits.